# Recover files deleted during windows installation

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

I had windows 7 installed on my computer and somehow it stopped working after trying for few times I decided to reinstall windows 7 hoping that files in c drive will be moved to windows.old but it didn't happen.  C drive had xampp folder with all my projects which got deleted. I tried using recuva to restore files (php,css,html etc), it does find and recover all files successfully but when I open my files instead of my code I see numbers, do this mean my files are corrupted ? Is there any way to solve this.

on opening my files with editors i see something like:

0515 1106 0619 010e 2c20 0f06 1423 0c11

2421 021e 2809 1407 5020 0202 020f 0905

Comment: Do the files have the correct extensions? This sound very much like a case where [source control](https://github.com/) would have helped.

Comment: @Burgi yes extensions are correct

Answer (score 0):

Normally PHP and CSS files are essentially plaintext files.

I ran the sample content you provided through a HEX to UTF converter. The hex codes, for the most part refer to Cyrillic characters. The very first character is `ԕ` (see this site for more [conversions](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=0515&mode=hex)). This appears to match up with your user in that a form of Cyrillic is your local language.

It could be an artefact of the recovery process that the file has lost its UTF8 encoding. You maybe able to find an online tool that will convert the entire file from HEX to UTF8.

You can easily change the encoding in Notepad++ with the following menu options:
[image: Screenshot of the file encoding type in Notepad++]

I stand by my original comment that you should seriously consider [source control](https://github.com/) in future to prevent future loss of code.